# What is the twig template name for a node edit form?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

In Drupal 8, what is the twig template name for a node edit form for a **custom content type** called for example "device".

- For a default node we use node-edit-form.html.twig
- So what is the edit template name for a custom content type ?

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you !

Answer (score 6):

You could have a look at [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2605562#comment-11531083). It suggests adding a theme suggestion like this:

> This feels hacky, but it's the best I can come up with. First add this
>   code to your admin .theme file (likely a sub-theme of Seven):
>
> ```
> function NAMEOFTHEME_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
>    if ($hook == 'node_edit_form') {
>      if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
>       $content_type = $node->bundle();
>      }
>      else {
>        $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
>        $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
>        $content_type = $path_args[3];
>      }
>      $suggestions[] = 'node_edit_form__' . $content_type;
>    } 
>  }
> ```
>
> Next, create twig templates in your theme's template directory in the form
>   of **node-edit-form--NODE-TYPE-SEPARATED-WITH-DASHES.html.twig**.

Comment: Approach looks pretty ok, but there is no reason for parsing the url like that, just get the node type with \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_type') (not sure about node type, would have to look up the route to be certain)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Neograph734's answer and Berdir his comment on it, the node type is indeed already available (no need get it out of the path). I would recommend to add the theme suggestion using:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for node_edit_form.
 */
function example_theme_suggestions_node_edit_form_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();

  if ($node = $route_match->getParameter('node')) {
    // When editing an existing node, add the node's bundle as the theme hook
    // suggestion.
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $node->bundle();
  } elseif ($node_type = $route_match->getParameter('node_type')) {
    // When a new node is created, the node type (object) is provided.
    $suggestions[] = $variables['theme_hook_original'] . '__' . $node_type->id();
  }

  return $suggestions;
}
```

This allows you to write targeted Twig templates and/or pre-process functions. When your node type's machine name is *device*, your Twig template should be named `node-edit-form--device.html.twig` and your pre-process function `example_preprocess_node_edit_form__device(&$variables)`, where example is the name of your theme (or module).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the complete steps it took me to implement on D9.2.10

1. [Create subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/creating-sub-themes) of admin theme seven
2. Install and enable new admin theme (note: enable through drop down)
3. create hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter in new admin *.theme

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter() for node_edit_form.
 */
function NAMEOFTHEME_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
   if ($hook == 'node_edit_form') {
     if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      $content_type = $node->bundle();
     }
     else {
       $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
       $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);
       $content_type = $path_args[3];
     }
     $suggestions[] = 'node_edit_form__' . $content_type;
   } 
 }
```

4. Copy seven's `node-edit-form.html.twig` to new subtheme's templates directory.
5. Create a node bundle specific override `node-edit-form--BUNDLE-NAME.html.twig`
6. Clear caches

Note: I did not need to override the theme for the form in a hook_form_alter for it to pick up node_edit_form.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to theme a specific form, for example the edit form of a node type, then all you have to do is

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    // form id (weather it's an edit node for or a new node form)
    'node_NODE_CONTENT_TYPE_edit_form' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then create a twig file node-NODE-CONTENT-TYPE-edit-form.html.twig

and theme it like so:

```
{{ form.field_MACHINE_NAME_OF_FIELD }}
{{ form.field_MACHINE_NAME_OF_FIELD2 }}
...
{# this prints out the submit button #}
{{ form.actions }}
{# you need to have this for the form to work properly #}
{{ form|without('name', 'field_MACHINE_NAME_OF_FIELD2', 'field_MACHINE_NAME_OF_FIELD3') }}
```