# How to override node add template for custom content type?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a custom content type named called "circular". For Admin user the "circular" node add form is opening using administration theme (i.e. Seven). But for Authenticated user the node add form is opening using my custom theme. I want to override template of the node add/edit form the custom theme.

I created page--node--add.html.twig in the template folder of the custom theme and used {{ form }} to render the form. But blank page is coming.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/231192/what-is-the-twig-template-name-for-a-node-edit-form/308548#308548. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/308548/69482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template will be used when a node edit form specifies 'node_edit_form' as its #theme callback. Otherwise, by default, node add/edit forms will be themed by form.html.twig.

Try this on your theme:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function YOURTHEME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#theme'] = ['node_edit_form'];
}
```

After this your theme can read template node-edit-form.html.twig.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21content-edit%21node-edit-form.html.twig/8.2.x

Answer (score -1):

Great tip, and what about the same but but a specific content type ? I don't want all content types node forms templates to be overwritten. (I'm on Drupal 9)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133798)